# Dynamically Call Different Python Files with dynamically importing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I have a folder structure like

```
Current Folder > DC > F >
```

Current contains a A.py file which I will execute, which is my main py file.

F Folder will have numerous *.py files which all have a class and its constructor

DC Folder will have few *.py files which the *.py files in F is using

I am importing a xml file which I am reading from the main A.py file, which is of the following format.

```
<Test>DC\F\TestCase1</Test>
<Test>DC\F\TestCase2</Test>
```

I have my main A.py which does this

```
if (line.startswith("<Test>")):
      result = re.search('<Test>(.*)</Test>', line)
      filename = result.group(1).split('\\')[-1]
      eval(filename)(self.getWebDriver())
```

and it works fine. But the problem is, it is expecting this

```
from DC.F.TestCase1 import TestCase1
from DC.F.TestCase2 import TestCase2
```

How do I get rid of this import statements, so that A.py can be independent of further editing and can run entirely by the input files?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me: where are these import statements coming from? what is the result that you're trying to achieve? what do you expect to return from `eval('DC\F\TestCase2')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `impportlib` python module for this? Give it a go, it might be what you are looking for.

Edit: specifically the `importlib.import_module()` function.

The docs are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module)